# Allowing users to subscribe to categories

Tags: performance, html, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am working on a Rails 3 application, and am having some trouble with my user/edit view. In this application, Users can subscribe to Categories. Users and Categories have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship through a join table (`categories_users`).

In my user/edit view, I need to display a list of checkboxes for the various categories so the user can edit his subscriptions. I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
<div id="category-checklist">
  <% Category.roots.order('name ASC').each do |category| %>
    <ul>
      <li class="parent <%= category.name %>">
        <%= check_box_tag "user[category_ids][]", category.id, @user.categories.include?(category) %> <span><%= category.name %></span>
      </li>

      <ul id="children-<%= category.id %>" class="children-list">
        <% category.children.order('name ASC').each do |child| %>
          <li class="child <%= child.name %>">
            <%= check_box_tag "user[category_ids][]", child.id, @user.categories.include?(child) %> <span><%= child.name %></span>
          </li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The `Category` model uses the ancestry gem for hierarchy, which is there the `roots` and `children` methods come from. Roots returns all the parent categories, and children returns all of the sub-categories for a given parent.

The really problematic part of this code seems to be `@user.categories.include?(child)` which is running 81 separate queries (one for each child category). This line is used to check if the category is currently subscribed to by the user -- if so, the checkbox is marked checked. Is there a better/faster way to accomplish this?

For reference, here is the join table's schema definition - I tried to put an index on the foreign keys thinking it would speed things up, but this is still very slow compared to the rest of my app.

```ruby
create_table "categories_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "category_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

add_index "categories_users", ["category_id"], :name => "index_categories_users_on_category_id"
add_index "categories_users", ["user_id"], :name => "index_categories_users_on_user_id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you load the user, you can include the categories using eager loading.

```
@user = User.includes(:categories).find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@categories = @user.categories.all
```

Comment: Thanks - you know, I had it setup this way in my users controller and I didn't realize that Devise moves everything to use their registrations_controller. I added "@categories = @user.categories.all" to the Devise controller's edit method and page load dropped exponentially! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.